# What is the complexity of this code that returns all subsets?

Tags: recursion, subset

I am analysing the complexity of this code:

```cpp
class Solution {
private:
    void solve(vector<int>& nums, int index, vector<vector<int>> &ans, vector<int> v) {
        if (index >= nums.size()) {
            ans.push_back(v);
            v.clear();
            return;
        }
        //exclude
        solve(nums, index + 1, ans, v);
        //include
        int val = nums[index];
        v.push_back(val);
        solve(nums, index + 1, ans, v);
    }

public:
    vector<vector<int>> subsets(vector<int>& nums) {
        int index = 0;
        vector<int> v;
        vector<vector<int>> ans;
        solve(nums, 0, ans, v);
        return ans;
    }
};
```

I am expecting a space complexity of O(n), as the maximum space occupied in the function call stack will be equal to n, and constant space is used in each function as only a pointer of an array will be copied. Have no idea about time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

As you have two recursive calls at each internal level of the recursion tree, the next level in the recursion tree has twice the number of execution contexts as in the current level. The depth of recursion is fixed to . So we have a time complexity of O(2).

If we include the space allocated for `ans` then also the space complexity is O(2) because at each parent node in the recursion tree, we perform `v.push_back(val)`, which allocates an extra entry in `v`. And although `v` is cleared repeatedly, its contents are *copied* into the result vector, so that `clear` is not reducing the overall memory usage.

If you want to exclude `ans` from this consideration, then the the space complexity is O(), as we can consider that `v` just reuses the same memory over and over again, and also the recursion stack use is O().